# Iframe Access PHP File In Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, iframe

i want to make iframe in codeigniter which access a php file in my local folder. Like this

```
<iframe src="assets/kcfinder/browse.php?type=files&dir=/assets/admin/images" frameborder="0" ></iframe>
```

But the display always redirect it to 404 page. How can i fix it?

Thank you very much.

Comment: without knowing the folder structure, how can we know why does server return 404 ?

Comment: the folder and file is already exist. the return 404 because i didn't know what function that must i use to write in controller. i have been make a controller to redirect that url, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using CI you are ill-advised to call a php file directly. Create a controller instead and call that instead. Something like:

```
    <?php

    require_once dirname(__FILE__) . "/base.php";

        class fck extends BaseController {

        function __construct() {
            parent::__construct();
            $this->load->model('myModel');
        }


        function browse($type,$dir)  { 
            $data['directory'] = $this->myModel->loadDirContent($type,$dir);
            $this->load->view("fck/browse", $data); 
        }
    }
    ?>
```

Your iframe then looks like this:

```
<iframe src="/fck/browse/files/assets/admin/images" frameborder="0" ></iframe>
```

Note that after 'browse' in the URI above you are effectively submitting data. First what is read out as "$type" by the browse function, i.e. "files" then the path itself, i.e. data that contains dashes. This is no longer part of an URL so to speak.